# How to make a background resizable for different screens?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

So I am just trying to make a background that can fit different screens. This is what I have so far:

```
class GameScene: SKScene,   {

let scaleFactor: CGFloat = 0.0

override init(size: CGSize) {
    super.init(size: size)
    scaleFactor = self.size.width / 320.0
}

func createBackgroundNode() -> SKNode {

    let backgroundNode = SKNode()
    let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Background")
    background.setScale(scaleFactor)
    background.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2  , y: self.frame.height / 2 )
    background.zPosition = 0
    addChild(background)

    return backgroundNode
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am coding in objective c, however I think my answer will work for you. You will just have to adapt the code to the swift. I add the following method just after implementation:

```
- (void)ScreenSize
{
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {

        CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
        if (result.height == 480) {
            //Do something
        } else if (result.height == 568) {
            //Do something
        } else if (result.height == 667) {
            //Do something
        } else if (result.height == 736) {
            //Do something
        }
    } else {
        //Do something for iPad here
    }
}
```

I used void here, but you can use something what fits your need, like SKSpriteNode, etc.

Hope it helps,

Good luck.